# mysql_query update is not working though i am not getting any mysql errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

i just wrote an update query for mysql database. the problem is neither its showing any mysql error nor it is updating the row. my_sql_rows is always outputing false which means nothing has been updated in my tabe 
the code is as follows

```
if(isset($_POST['update_subject']))
{  
    $id  = $_POST['id'];
    $menu_name  = $_POST['menu_name'];
    $visible  = $_POST['visible'];
    $position  = $_POST['position'];
    $content  = $_POST['content'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE subjects SET menu_name ='$menu_name', visible = $visible, position = $position,
                    content =    '$content'  WHERE id =  $id ")
                     or die("updation of '$menu_name' in table subjects failed due to : " . mysql_error ());
    if(mysql_affected_rows == 1 ) {
        echo "Updation of '$menu_name' in table subjects is done successfully !!! ";
    } else {
        echo "something went wrong. updation process is halted.";
    }   
}
```

its always returning me "something went wrong. updation process is halted " 
i know mysql commands are outdated but still i want to learn. thanx !

Comment: inb4 deprecation spamming

Comment: dint understand what you said

Comment: @JohnDoe Its not spamming when its true, trying to let the OP there using an outdated API is more helpful then being a `im first troll`

Comment: @JohnDoe Oh you. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli)

Answer (score 3):

Ita because youre using the taboo practice of not incorporating brackets with your if statements, in addition to need the parenthesis after the function

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1 ){
    echo "Updation of '$menu_name' in table subjects is done successfully !!! ";
}
else{
    echo "something went wrong. updation process is halted.";
}
```

Comment: its not about message ..update is not reflecting in database also

Comment: Figured it would, no problem

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè ;)

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_affected_rows` is function and thus you need parentheses after it like:

```
$result = mysql_query($yourquery);
if(mysql_affected_rows($result) === 1) {
  // logic
}
```

Now on with the deprecation spam...

[`ext/mysql` should not be used for new projects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php):

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the mysqli or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also the MySQL API Overview for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Instead you should use [`mysqli`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) with the mysql driver.

Comment: still the problem persists ... by the way problem is in upate query as updation is not reflecting in database

Comment: Well you may have another problem because the code you had before should have at least generated a warning about a missing constant. I bet if you turn `display_errors` on youll get some error messages.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things,

1. `UPDATE` query needs to have `'` quotes around the column values if they are strings. So check the query.

   ```
   mysql_query("UPDATE subjects SET menu_name ='$menu_name', visible = '$visible', position = '$position', content = '$content'  WHERE id =  '$id' ")
   ```
2. `mysql_affected_rows` is a function, so it has to be,

   ```
   if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1 )
   ```

**Note:** Mysql_* extensions are deprecated. Use `Mysqli` or `PDO` if possible.

Comment: only menu_name is string so i have put quotes and also i have corrected (mysql_affected_rows() == 1 ) but still... :(

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to this with PDO + cleaner looking code try:

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=databasename", 'dbuser', 'dbpassword');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Cannot connect to mySQL server.');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['update_subject'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['id'])){

        $sql = "UPDATE subjects SET menu_name = :menu_mame,
                                    visible   = :visible,
                                    position  = :position,
                                    content   = :content
                                WHERE id = :id";

        $update = array(':menu_name'=>$_POST['menu_name'],
                        ':visible'=>$_POST['visible'],
                        ':position'=>$_POST['position'],
                        ':content'=>$_POST['content'],
                        ':id'=>$_POST['id']);

        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($update);

        $affected = $query->rowCount();

        if($affected > 0 ){
            echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['menu_name'])." updated successfully !!!";
        }else{
            echo "Something went wrong or no rows were found tobe updated";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: as of now i dont know pdo and its usage. still thankyou for your help i can refer to it sometimes later :)

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are frowned upon in the SO community and for good reason, there broken! Its like why drive an old rusty mini cooper with **no windows** if your offered a free upgrade to a dodge charger that has bullet proof tinted windows. It wont take long to learn to drive it and once you do your get all the girls ;p

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇ ƇhƐȓ0nè FYI it's 'affected' not 'effected'.  Don't mean to be a grammar nazi, but it made me cringe.

Comment: @l̕aͨŵƦȆ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝ƞCͭ̏ȇƇhƐȓ0nè if i could +1 you again for that comparison i so would